# ׁׁׁׁHow to return value from bash file to jenkinsfile?

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have the following jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        VERSION=""
    }
    stages {
        stage ("release"){
            steps {
                script {
                    ${VERSION}=sh(returnStdout: true, script:$("./bashscript.sh).trim())
                }
            }
        }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is simple, I want to call to bash file that returns a value to an environment variable in my Jenkinsfile.

I have 2 questions: 1. how to return value from a bash file? 2. how to insert it to the environment variable in the Jenkinsfile?

That's my .sh file:

```
# !/bin/bash
if [ some condition... ] 
then
    some commands....
    return "value"
else
    some commands....
    return "other value"
fi
```

I've searched for a long time and found nothing, is it possible at all?

NOTE: I saw many solutions for groovy but I need it in the pipeline...

Comment: `how to return value from bash file?` Not sure what is that suppose to mean. Are you trying to replace a variable from jenkins from a file using bash?

Comment: yes, I want to return variable from bash file to variable in jenkinsfile

Comment: While you've accepted the answer, seems convoluted, as is the Q. Is the value you are trying to "return" simply a result code (0,1-255)? Pipeline sh step has [return code (optional)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script). And this [code-maven](https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-collect-exit-code-from-external-commands) example has a clever way to aggregate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For setting variable example from shell for jenkins use **returnStdout: true** .
   In your script echo what you need

```
myVal = sh(script: ' ./myFunc.ksh ', returnStdout: true)
```

2. Execute functions from bash as they suppose to return a variable.
   To make function visible you need to source it file (import) example is below

```
# for point 2 
#/bin/bash
# content of your file ./myfileFunc.ksh
function myFunc {
   typeset l_in_param1="$1"
   
   if [[ $l_in_param1 == "A" ]]; then
      echo "VAL_A"  
   elif [[ $l_in_param1 == "B" ]]; then
      echo "VAL_B"   
   else
      echo "ERROR VAL" >&2
   fi
}
# source it
source ./myfileFunc.ksh

#use :
val1=$(myFunc A)
val2=$(myFunc C)
```

3. Script returns data to the standard and error output so you can store it in variable later by reading from there using , returnStdout: true

myVal = sh(script: ' ./myFunc.ksh ', returnStdout: true)

```
# content of your file ./myFunc.ksh

typeset l_in_param1="$1"
   
if [[ $l_in_param1 == "A" ]]; then
    echo "VAL_A"  
elif [[ $l_in_param1 == "B" ]]; then
    echo "VAL_B"   
else
    echo "ERROR VAL" >&2
fi


l_result1=$( ./myFunc.ksh A ) 
l_result2=$( ./myFunc.ksh C )

echo $l_result1; 
echo $l_result2;
```

Here l_result2 will be null as we moved error to error output

[Execution of code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTGRH.png)

Comment: but how can I return it to my jenkins file? I dont need to echo it...

Comment: env.envType = sh(script: ' ./myFunc.ksh ', returnStdout: true).trim()
all that was in echo went to std out so you can read it  -->  returnStdout: true

Comment: in bash word return used for error code passing to caller. Echo is doing return of function value thus here echo :
```
function test { echo "VAL" ; return 1; } ;
val=$(test);
echo $? ;
echo $val ;
```

Comment: OK its working fine but it return output of all commands in script, how can i get the last one(the one i did echo to)

Comment: i suggest to create functions and invoke them to return specific value.
Otherwise you need to redirect all other commands to error output like :
cmd1 >&2;
cmd2 >&2;
cmd3 >&2;
echo "last"